# How did Sherlock narrow his questioning to four women in The Sign of Three?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

I just watched *The Sign of Three*, where several women claim to have dated a ghost. At some point, Sherlock narrows his questioning down to four women.

What was his criteria to choose these four women in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No explicit explanation is given.

## We have to assume he's using his deductive abilities.

Recall that he's not actually interviewing these women ***in person***, the *"filtering"* is actually taking place **in his mind**.

He's actually reviewing stories posted on the fictitious idatedaghost.com.

[image]

Thereafter, he "speaks" with the selected few on message boards / forums to get more details and compare notes...

[image]